# Вызов JS функции из WebView выдаёт ошибку "function is not defined"

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

При попытке вызвать функцию MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString() из WebView

```
String textToSearch = editTextSearchInText.getText().toString();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    article_web_view.evaluateJavascript("MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('" + textToSearch + "')", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Возвращается null, а в консоли следующее:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString is not defined", source:  (1)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вызвать функцию JS из WebView? Почему возникает ошибка "функция не определена"? 
Код JS из WebView ниже:

```
<script > 
var MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
    function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement (element, keyword){
        if (element) {
            if (element.nodeType == 3) {
                while (true) {
                    var value = element.nodeValue;
                    var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);
                    if (idx < 0) break;
                    var span = document.createElement("span");
                    var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx, keyword.length));
                    span.appendChild(text);
                    span.setAttribute("class", "MyAppHighlight");
                    span.style.backgroundColor = "#C5DFEA";
                    text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx + keyword.length));
                    element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
                    var next = element.nextSibling;
                    element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                    element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                    element = text;
                    window.scrollTo(0, findPos(span));
                    MyApp_SearchResultCount++;
                }
            } else if (element.nodeType == 1) {
                if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "select") {
                    for (var i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i], keyword);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function findPos (obj) {var curtop = -100; if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return[curtop];
    }}
    function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString (keyword) {MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights();
    MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());}function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement (element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
            if (element.getAttribute("class") == "MyAppHighlight") {
                var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, element);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                return true;
            } else {
                var normalize = false;
                for (var i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                        normalize = true;
                    }
                }
                if (normalize) {
                    element.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;}
    function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights () {
        MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
        MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
    }
    function findImage (x, y){
        return document.elementFromPoint(x, y).src;
    }</script >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то столкнётся со схожей проблемой, то решение было предложено вот здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656305/calling-the-js-function-from-webview-produces-an-error-function-is-not-defined/42656992#42656992